# Internet Explorer 'input:checked + label:before' styling is not rendered

Tags: css, internet-explorer, checkbox, css-selectors, pseudo-element

I'm having some trouble getting the `:checked` styling for my custom checkboxes to display in Internet Explorer.

They work perfectly fine in Chrome.

[image]

... but in IE

[image]

Here's the relevant styling

```
input[type="radio"], input[type="checkbox"] {
    opacity: 1;
    position: absolute;
    top: -9999;

    & + label {
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
}

input[type="radio"] + label:before,
input[type="checkbox"] + label:before {
    content: '\f3fd';
    font-family: 'Ionicons';
    width: 26px;
    height: 20px;
    border: 2px solid #45555F;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: transparent;
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    transition: all 0.3s linear;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    padding: 0 2px;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked + label:before,
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:before {
    content: '\f383';
    font-family: 'Ionicons';
    font-size: 24px;
    width: 26px;
    height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 0 2px;
    border: 2px solid #45555F;
    color: #8ec549;
}

input[type="radio"] + label:before {
    border-radius: 50% !important;
}
```

I did also notice that Internet Explorer simply removes the styling on load...

[image]

Thanks for any help!

EDIT: Codepen Demo (This demo does not work in IE either)

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rLJqyK

Comment: What is the IE version?

Comment: The images in the question are IE11, but the issue occurs on IE10 too!

Comment: Your best bet is to create a runnable HTML snippet where we can examine the problem

Comment: @JuanMendes I've updated the question with a Codepen demo.

Comment: Your codepen works in IE11 for me (I see the green checkmarks).

Comment: @rgthree It doesn't seem to work for me, I am using BrowserStack though..?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As opposed to modifying the `:before` pseudo element on checked I simply used the `:after` pseudo element for the active state and flick between opacities to hide and show them accordingly.

Thanks for anybody who helped.

Answer (score 1):

Try another approach, I usually use the approach formatted below.

> The important point here is: we should use **'for'** attribute on the *'label'* element so that it is linked to the corresponding *'input'* element.

This will work in IE as well.

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}
label {
  padding-left: 25px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}
label::before {
 content: "";
 width: 16px;
 height: 16px;
 border: 1px solid #aaa;
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
}
label p {
  display: inline-block;
}
label input[type="checkbox"]:checked + p::after {
 content: "";
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 width: 10px;
 height: 5px;
 border-left: 2px solid;
 border-bottom: 2px solid;
 transform: rotate(-45deg);
 left: 3px;
 top: 4px;
 color: #3da5c3;
}
```

```html
<label for="testInput">
  <input type="checkbox" name="test" id="testInput" value=1 />
  <p>Test Checkbox</p>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a duplicate of [In IE11 using pseudo element ::before and display:table-cell and glyphicons contens wont show up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29379602/in-ie11-using-pseudo-element-before-and-displaytable-cell-and-glyphicons-cont).

In short, there's a [bug in IE10 and 11](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/796188/pseudo-element-display-table-cell-font-ignored) where the `font` style is ignored for pseudo elements with `table-cell` display.

As mentioned in the presumed duplicate issue, an appropriate fix would be to use some other `display` type for the pseudo element in conjunction with any necessary adjustments to your `width` and `height` styles.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're facing is a known **`IE10 - IE11`** bug, where these two browsers tend to **completely disregard the font declaration in pseudo elements with `display: table-cell`**. That means that properties as **`font`**, **`font-size`**, **`font-family`**, **`color`** etc will all be struck.

**To circumvent this bug**, it would suffice in your case to:

▶ Use **`display: table-cell`** with an actual element instead of a pseudo-element, or

▶ Change **`display: table-cell`** to **`display: inline-block`** or some other **`non-table-cell`** value for your pseudo-element.

▶ Declare a **`float`** property which has a value other than **`none`** so that it turns **`display: table-cell`** to **`display: block`**.

---

Here are some questions that face an issue with **`display: table-cell`** as well that may be of any help:

▶ [IE not coloring :before as table-cell, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24693227/ie-not-coloring-before-as-table-cell-why)

▶ [Positioning of div inside display:table-cell in IE 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17848409/positioning-of-div-inside-displaytable-cell-in-ie-10)

▶ [Display table-cell on pseudo element in IE11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29332318/display-table-cell-on-pseudo-element-in-ie11)